# how can I  block sms and call?

Tags: android

How can I block sms and call from selected number? Is it possible to create a dialog for received sms?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `BroadcastMessages` which are broadcasted when an incoming call is detected, or when any sms text message arrives, then can perform specified action.

also look for `<intent-filter>` .